# Confusion about Pareto Principle and Pareto distribution

Tags: pareto-distribution, diversity

The Pareto principle, applied to wealth for example, says that around 20% of the population holds 80% of the wealth. Accordingly, it is said that a person's wealth follows a Pareto distribution.

I'm confused about two things:

1. The Pareto distribution has infinite support. What is 80% of infinity? Do we consider a finite support?
2. Doesn't the exponential distribution lead to an even more strict distribution of wealth since the exponential function decays faster than a power law?

Comment: It might help to think of the Pareto *principle* as a discretization of the Pareto *distribution*.

Comment: On the topic of wealth concentration question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/79784/10479 can be useful.

Comment: It's 80% of the total of the outcome, not 80% of the support or range possible in principle.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid I did not understand. What does total outcome mean?

Comment: Total outcome could mean total _income_ (word play here is accidental). It could mean total wealth, total pollution, total production, whatever. The principle can't apply unless it makes sense to talk about totals.

Comment: @Yves That link was very helpful. I was only thinking of the Pareto distribution with shape = 1, thus infinite means.